# Navigating two times from landscape to portrait in iOS

Tags: ios, navigation, landscape, landscape-portrait, portrait

Button pressed from current screen is landscape and its moves to other screen which is locked to Portrait in iOS. Version 17 OS its coming as two times and lower versions like iOS 15 0r 16 in that its working fine. What will be issue for that and please let me know if it can be solved.

Here is the Video Link is shared https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E_y9N9APHHfsPxGmORMgGmE2AW5BRaMY/view?usp=share_link

Comment: At least can you share the code? Btw, the link is disabled.

Comment: @son  Now you can access the video file